# Serializable Interface with non-serializable objects

Tags: android, serialization, interface

I have an inner interface implementing Serializable.
I am seeing crashes saying that my object is not serializable, but I am not sure whether it is because the interface is declared in a class, or because of something else.

I know that classes with non serializable objects like Activity cannot be serialized, but what about interfaces with methods returning Activity objects, for instance?

To be clearer, I have

```
public class MyClass extends Parcelable{

    MyInterface mInterface;

    public interface MyInterface implements Serializable{
     Activity getActivity();
    }
}
```

and I get crash logs when trying to write the Parcel

```
dest.writeSerializable(mInterface);
```

Stack trace reads:

```
Caused by java.io.NotSerializableException: com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1233)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1597)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1558)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1227)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1597)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1558)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1227)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1597)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1558)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1227)
   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1757)
   at MyClass.writeToParcel(MyClass.java:87)
```

What is the most likely reason for not being serialized:

- that interface is inside a class that is not serializable
- that interface includes an activity

?

Comment: Interfaces do not get serialized. Objects do. Objects are instances of some specific class. If your object is capable of returning an `Activity`, then you are going to crash, because `Activity` is not able to be serialized. At most, model objects might be marked as `Serializable`, and a model object should not have a reference to any sort of UI construct like an `Activity`, `Fragment`, `View`, etc.

Comment: I added the more precise example. I understand your reply, but I would like to find a clear troubleshooting direction for my problem. Thanks.

Comment: "I get crash logs" -- the stack trace should be giving you some clues.

Comment: as mentioned earlier, it is a "Not Serializable Exception". But I pasted the important part of the stack trace in the next edit.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the most likely reason for not being serialized

With regards to your options:

- A nested interface is essentially static in scope, so there should be no problems with `Serializable` with respect to it
- I am assuming that by "that interface includes an activity" you mean "that interface has a method that returns an `Activity", which is not directly relevant, as neither interfaces nor methods are serialized

Objects and their fields get serialized. So, the fact that `MyInterface` has a method that returns `Activity` is not strictly a problem, as it might be that the particular object being serialized would return `null` for that method.

However, if the object has a field that contains an `Activity` (directly or indirectly) — and your method happens to use that field for its return value — then you are in trouble, because `Activity` and lots of things that `Activity` holds onto cannot be serialized.

And, based on your stack trace, my guess is that your object is holding onto an `Activity`.

In Android app development, using `Serializable` is a code smell. There is nothing strictly wrong with it. But the vast majority of times I see people on Stack Overflow trying to use it, it is because they are trying to solve the wrong problem (e.g., pass a listener between activities) with the wrong solution (i.e., use `Serializable` on the listener interface).

Comment: Thanks, I understand much better now. Could you please develop the "pass a listener between activities". It might be my "wrong problem". My code got very complex after trying to solve the famous AsyncTask problem for newbies, where you're allowed to use the UI Thread in Pre and Post Execute, but where you're not advised to hold UI references nor WeakReference. Then I created a bunch of Listeners and here I am.

Comment: I should add to my eternal existential questions, that : why some users experience this crash while others (including me) never see it happening? If it is not serializable, it should never be serializable on any device nor any android version, right?

Comment: @Myoch: With regards to your latter comment, I don't know when/how this code is getting called. I would expect to fail fairly regularly, if the object is truly referencing an `Activity`. With regards to `AsyncTask`, to be honest, that's kinda old. The best (if not only) decent pattern for using one was from a retained fragment. Modern Android app development has moved onto other techniques: `LiveData`, RxJava, Kotlin coroutines, and the like.

Comment: Thanks, I started my app 5 years ago, and increased its complexity and features over time, but I never really updated myself further than what crashes and compile errors forced me to. It sounds dumb, I know. For my defense, android dev is not my real job, but I am trying to make quite decent apps. I'll teach myself some Live Data and RxJava as a start. I like Kotlin, but I'm scared of porting this huge project to it without having more experience with Kotlin.

Comment: But really, I have 85% crash free users,so that'll stay an enigma.